# How do I make the Pipeline skip the step (using "passthrough") and all params that applies to that step in param_grid?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm creating a pipeline in sklearn using PCA and skipping this step using "passthrough".
For PCA I'm testing several values of the `n_components` parameter.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X_train, y_train = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=10)


param_grid = {
    'reduce_dim': [PCA(), 'passthrough'],
    'reduce_dim__n_components': [1,2,3]
}

pipeline = Pipeline(
        steps=[
            ('reduce_dim', None), 
            ('regressor', LinearRegression())
        ]
    )

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipeline, 
    param_grid=param_grid, 
    verbose=10
)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

What I want to achieve is 3 fits for PCA with `n_components=[1,2,3]` and 1 fit without PCA.

> Fitting 5 folds for each of 4 candidates, totalling 20 fits

What I get is 3 fits for PCA and 3 fits without PCA (I don't need to test all three possibilities of `n_components` without PCA):

> Fitting 5 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 30 fits

and then a runtime error which basically says that I cannot assign n_components value to "passthrough" (str object)

```
[CV 1/5; 4/6] START reduce_dim=passthrough, reduce_dim__n_components=1...
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set_params'
```

**How do I make the pipeline skip the step (`reduce_dim` in that case) and all params that applies to that step?**

I know that I can use param_grid like this:

```py
param_grid = [
    {
        'reduce_dim': [PCA()],
        'reduce_dim__n_components': [1,2,3]
    },
    {}
]
```

but can it be done in a more elegant way, because in more complex scenarios the code is getting really messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter grid you want can also be defined in a single dictionary for a single parameter:

```py
param_grid = {
    'reduce_dim' = [PCA(n_components=1), PCA(n_components=2), PCA(n_components=3), 'passthrough']
}
```

This has the advantage of avoiding the need to define several dictionaries which might be less "messy".

Comment: Ok, but what if I have multiple params and values, then I would have to write down all the combinations in the code.